# Count the occurrences of the elements in list

Tags: python

I want to make a function that get a list, like:

```
['comp1', 'comp2', 'comp1', 'mycomp', 'mycomp']
```

And return a dictionary that the key's is the name of the computers and the values is how many times the same name\key's repeated in the list.

Like if the list get input:

```
["computer17", "computer6", "comp", "computer17"]
```

So the return is:

```
["computer17":"2",...]
```

Comment: What number do your expect for "comp"?

Comment: i changed the question @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: I changed the question @timgeb

Comment: I changed the question @VigneshKalai

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest to way to count the items in a list is using a `Counter` object (Counter is a child-class of the built in dictionary):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> computers = ['computer17', 'computer6', 'comps', 'computer17']
>>> Counter(computers)
Counter({'computer17': 2, 'comps': 1, 'computer6': 1})
```

Excerpt from the docs:

> class Counter(__builtin__.dict)
>
> Dict subclass for counting hashable items.  Sometimes called a bag
>   or multiset.  Elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts
>   are stored as dictionary values.